# shinysurvey throws error with matrix input type

Tags: r, shiny

The following shiny app throws an error when I click on one of the choices, if I use `input_type == matrix`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinysurveys)
   

df <- as.data.frame(tibble::tribble(
  ~question, ~option, ~input_type, ~input_id, ~dependence, ~dependence_value, ~required,
  "I like sushi.", "Strongly Disagree",   "matrix", "matId", NA_character_, NA_character_, TRUE,
  "I like sushi.", "Moderately Disagree", "matrix", "matId", NA_character_, NA_character_, TRUE,
  "I like sushi.", "Slightly Disagree",   "matrix", "matId", NA_character_, NA_character_, TRUE,
  "I like sushi.", "Slightly Agree",      "matrix", "matId", NA_character_, NA_character_, TRUE,
  "I like sushi.", "Moderately Agree",    "matrix", "matId", NA_character_, NA_character_, TRUE,
  "I like sushi.", "Strongly Agree",      "matrix", "matId", NA_character_, NA_character_, TRUE
))


ui <- fluidPage(
  surveyOutput(
    df = df,
    # theme = NULL,
    survey_title = "Hello, World!",
    survey_description = "Welcome! This is a demo survey showing off the {shinysurveys} package."
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  renderSurvey()
  
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Congrats, you completed your first shinysurvey!",
      "You can customize what actions happen when a user finishes a survey using input$submit."
    ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

## Warning: Error in &&: 'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

But it works if I replace `matrix` with `mc`. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: The problem seems to be connected with the `required` column. In particular, in the source code `df$required[1]` is referenced. If you change `required` to `FALSE` in the first row, the error disappears. However, if you change it in the second row, the error remains (although this is the same question).